# Passing parameters in correct format to a linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I am passing parameters to a linked server as follows:

```
DECLARE 
 @QRY01 VARCHAR(8000)
,@WIP_PRM VARCHAR(12)
--START SEARCHING WIP_AUTO_KEY IN COST_AUDIT_LOG FROM LAST RECORD INCLUDED IN tbl_WIPLOG1
SET @WIP_PRM = CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),(SELECT MAX(WIP_AUTO_KEY)  FROM tbl_WIPLOG1))

    SET @QRY01 = ' 
    SELECT  * 
    FROM
    OPENQUERY(LINKED_SERVER,
    ''SELECT DISTINCT
     QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG.WIP_AUTO_KEY
    ,QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG.WOO_AUTO_KEY
    FROM QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG 
    WHERE
    QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG.WIP_AUTO_KEY > '+CHAR(39) + CHAR(39)+CAST(@WIP_PRM AS nvarchar(500))+CHAR(39) + CHAR(39)+N''')

    EXEC(@QRY01)
```

It appears that the formatting of the parameter inside the OPENQUERY statement is incorrect or requires a keyword in front of it to designate it as text, since the entire statement is enclosed in brackets.   If I type the value of the parameter in as shown below the query works, but not in the above format.

```
 SET @QRY01 = ' 
    SELECT  * 
    FROM
    OPENQUERY(LINKED_SERVER,
    ''SELECT DISTINCT
     QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG.WIP_AUTO_KEY
    ,QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG.WOO_AUTO_KEY
    FROM QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG 
    WHERE
    QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG.WIP_AUTO_KEY > ''''1432697'''' '

EXEC(@QRY01)
```

How can I make the query accept the parameter in the proper format?

Comment: You don't need either `exec` or `sp_executesql` to run a query against a linked server. You can specify the server in the `FROM` clause, eg `FROM LINKED_SERVER.ThatDatabase.QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG ...`

Comment: do a `PRINT @QRY01` and examine the query

Comment: That does not seem to work - message 'Invalid object name'

Comment: Does `SELECT [name] FROM LINKED_SERVER.master.sys.databases;` return anything? If not, that `OPENQUERY` isn't working because you haven't configured `LINKED_SERVER` as a linked server.

Comment: `+N'''` doesn't look right, and your open parenthesis (`(`) on `OpenQuery` doesn't appear to have a matching close parenthesis (`)`). Perhaps `+N''')';`?

Comment: I forgot to type the closing parenthesis in the 2nd query above, but it does work  as I stated above.  The problem is with the data-type of the parameter that does not match the data type of the field that is being returned.  The field type is float, but inside the OPENQUERY it is apparently converted to a varchar.?  I am casting the parameter as nvarchar(500), but it doesn't give the desired result.   In the second code snippet above you can see that when instead of using the parameter, I type in a varchar , then the query works.  So then the field type matches the type of the value typed in.

Comment: The point of linked servers is to enable you to run sql statements on the linked server without having to use `openquery` and stuff like that - all you need is a fully qualified name for your database object - Server.Database.Schema.Table/Procedure/View

Comment: @Leon you don't need to use OPENQUERY. What is the name of the server, database and schema? Did you try a four-part name? If you tried and failed, post the query so people can point what's wrong with it. Don't assume that linked servers are broken

Comment: @Leon string concatenation can easily fail if the parameter contains even a single `'` character. That's how SQL injection attacks happen.

Answer (score 0):

@leon, you need to take out the CHAR(39) to streamline the query.

Here is a modified version below:

```
    DECLARE 
     @QRY01 VARCHAR(8000)
    ,@WIP_PRM VARCHAR(12)
    --START SEARCHING WIP_AUTO_KEY IN COST_AUDIT_LOG FROM LAST RECORD INCLUDED IN tbl_WIPLOG1
    SET @WIP_PRM = CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),(SELECT MAX(WIP_AUTO_KEY)  FROM tbl_WIPLOG1))

        SET @QRY01 = ' 
        SELECT  * 
        FROM
        OPENQUERY(LINKED_SERVER,
        ''SELECT DISTINCT
         QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG.WIP_AUTO_KEY
        ,QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG.WOO_AUTO_KEY
        FROM QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG 
        WHERE
      QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG.WIP_AUTO_KEY > '+CAST(@WIP_PRM AS nvarchar(500))+ N''')'

EXEC(@QRY01)
```

This should give you this output:

```
    SELECT  * 
    FROM
    OPENQUERY(LINKED_SERVER,
    'SELECT DISTINCT
     QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG.WIP_AUTO_KEY
    ,QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG.WOO_AUTO_KEY
    FROM QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG 
    WHERE
  QCTL.WIP_AUDIT_LOG.WIP_AUTO_KEY > 1432697')
```

Comment: You don't need OPENQUERY to run queries against a linked server. String contatenation fails if the parameter contains even a single unexpected like `'` or '.' . That's how SQL injection attacks are carried out

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I am not sure your statment is correct. Actually, you need OPENQUERY. Openquery help "Executes the specified pass-through query on the specified linked server". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: No you don't. You need to use a four-part name for the table. Your link points to the OPENQUERY docs, not something specific to linked servers

Comment: They are all valid. Openquery is another option. Refrences: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsakthi/2011/05/08/best-performer-distributed-query-four-part-or-openquery-when-executing-linked-server-queries-in-sql-server/  and   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/aaa920bb-86aa-4acf-91d7-2006b72f389d/linked-server-four-part-naming-convention-vs-openquery?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: I agree that there are consequences. copied: The most difference between the OPENQUERY function and four-part names is the resources used. When using OPENQUERY, query plan is created and used in remote server bring only those rows in the result set. Otherwise, using four-part names will process the query locally. Using four-part names is the best practice solution for remote access from OLE DB data sources which will occur more than once, because the query plan is cached locally.

Comment: Thank you MEdwin.  I have been wasting an enormous amount of time exploring alternatives.  Your reply will help me to go forward now.  Thanks again.